# How can I use "name" from wmctrl?

Tags: autohotkey

When I do "wmctrl -l" from WSL2, I get

```
wmctrl.exe -l
ID:      Name:   Title:
-------------------------------------------------
13028    WindowsTerminal         C:\WINDOWS\system32\wmctrl.exe
```

..and when I do it from Windows, I get this:

```
ID:      Name:   Title:
-------------------------------------------------
13028    WindowsTerminal         Windows PowerShell
```

How can I use this in AutoHotKey, cause I seem only to be able to use the Title, as this will not work:

```
^!+t::
if WinExist("WindowsTerminal")
   WinActivate 
else
   Run wt
return
```

I'm able to match "Power", but that is the "title", which I don't want to match. I want to match on "name".

Also, what is the "name" here? It's not the executable name and it's not the Window Manager title, so I'm not sure what it really is;)

Comment: Create a shortcut of this app and rename it to **`wt`**. Copy that shortcut in the folder `C:\WINDOWS\system32`. Then you can run that program from your script (`Run wt`) or from the Run dialog box (press Win+R, type wt in the box and press Enter).

Comment: that's not answering the question of what the "name" column is, in the output of wmctrl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **Window Spy** tool to retrieve information about that window:

[image: Selecting window spy]
[image: Window Spy in use]

If the window's title isn't always the same, you can use its [ahk_class](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_class) or/and [ahk_exe](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_exe):

```
; e.g. for explorer:
if WinExist("ahk_class CabinetWClass")
   WinActivate

; or:
if WinExist("ahk_exe explorer.exe")
   WinActivate  

; or:
if WinExist("ahk_class CabinetWClass ahk_exe explorer.exe")
   WinActivate
```